# 500 internal server error in back end - Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, internal-server-error

I have installed new site in Joomla 2.5 and it was working fine at first,(front end and back end),
but today when I wanted to do some changes in the back end, after I log in to the site, It shows this error:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I read some questions that were like my problem,
I made some changes in configuration.php file as below:

```
$log_path='./logs';
$tmp_path = './tmp';
```

but it did not work.

Please help me:)

Comment: You will need the actual logs, specifically the error log from the server.  The configuration.php changes will mostly likely not change anything as 500 errors are normally compilation errors on the script.   Without the actual error from php it will be pretty much impossible to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Possible scenarions, 1) conflicting plugins; did you install any lately? 2) your host updated php/mysql versions? 3) did you update joomla? happened to me once, website wasn't working anymore after an update. As said by Doon, please check your error log!